# How can I optimize label encoding for large data sets (sci-kit learn)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using sci-kit learn's label encoding class to encode a a list of lists of strings into integer codes. i.e.

```
[[a,b,c],[b,c,d],[c,f,z]...,[a,v,z]]]
```

The LabelEncoder has already been instantiated and fit with the label names. What I'm trying to do is iterate through the list of lists and transform each one.

My first solution was to brute force iterate through the list.

```
for list in list_of_lists:
   label_encoder.transform(list)
```

As this scaled to the tens of thousands, it became extremely slow.

I tried to convert the list of lists into a Pandas dataframe and apply the .map method in Pandas to the dataset, but it's still very slow.

Is there any way to optimize the label encoder's transform? I'm not sure why it's so slow.

Comment: It might be a little faster if you work directly on the  `ndarrays`, apply it to the whole bunch at once and then transform them into a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of looping with `scikit-learn` you can try pure `numpy`, which I'm sure will be faster.

If you always have equal number of  elements (3?) in an inner list, then you can try something like:

**1. Prepare some data**:

```
n=5
xs = np.random.choice(list("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"),3*n).reshape((-1,3))
xs
array([['z', 'h', 'd'],
       ['g', 'k', 'y'],
       ['t', 'c', 'o'],
       ['f', 'b', 's'],
       ['x', 'n', 'z']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

**2. Encode**

```
np.unique(xs, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape((-1,3))
array([[13,  5,  2],
       [ 4,  6, 12],
       [10,  1,  8],
       [ 3,  0,  9],
       [11,  7, 13]])
```

**3. Timing**

```
n = 1000000
xs = np.random.choice(list("qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"),3*n).reshape((-1,3))

%timeit np.unique(xs, return_inverse=True)[1].reshape((-1,3))
849 ms ± 39.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Less than a second...

If you can show the full code of yours, we can compare runtime.

**EDIT: Moving back and forth with encoding**

As the question slightly changed due to the @JCDJulian's comment (see below), I am adding code snippet to show encoding/decoding at any point of data processing with the help of `dictionary`:

First, you'll need `dic`, if you wish to encode:

```
labels = np.unique(xs, return_inverse=True)[1]
dic = dict(zip(xs.flatten(),labels))
```

And the encoding process itself is:

```
ys = np.reshape([dic[v] for list in xs for v in list], (-1,3))
ys
array([[13,  5,  2],
       [ 4,  6, 12],
       [10,  1,  8],
       [ 3,  0,  9],
       [11,  7, 13]])
```

For decoding, you'll need `reverse_dic`:

```
reverse_dic = dict(zip(labels, xs.flatten()))
np.reshape([reverse_dic[v] for list in ys for v in list], (-1,3))
array([['z', 'h', 'd'],
       ['g', 'k', 'y'],
       ['t', 'c', 'o'],
       ['f', 'b', 's'],
       ['x', 'n', 'z']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

**EDIT 2: Random shape arrays**

For the sake of completeness, a solution for random shape arrays

Encode:

```
labels = np.unique(xs, return_inverse=True)[1]
dic = dict(zip(xs.flatten(),labels))
np.vectorize(dic.get)(xs)
array([[13,  5,  2],
       [ 4,  6, 12],
       [10,  1,  8],
       [ 3,  0,  9],
       [11,  7, 13]])
```

Decode:

```
reverse_dic = dict(zip(labels, xs.flatten()))
np.vectorize(reverse_dic.get)(ys)
array([['z', 'h', 'd'],
       ['g', 'k', 'y'],
       ['t', 'c', 'o'],
       ['f', 'b', 's'],
       ['x', 'n', 'z']],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Please note, the shapes of array do not show up in the code anywhere!

Comment: Hmm I see. The reason I like the Label Encoder class is because I need to be able to deterministically transform values elsewhere in the script and be able to convert back and forth from the encoding and the original values. I'm not sure that this answer can guarantee that.